# How to get the value populated in a combobox with the help of a Binding Source

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows form in which I want to get the values in a combo box. for this, I have created a binding source and bind it with an entity's property. Now, when I run the application, I am getting the value in the property with which I have bind the combo box. but still, the value is not getting displayed in the combo Box. Am I missing something here. I think I have to set its "Display Member". I know its a very small thing but its really bugging me off. I would appreciate any help provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GOT the answer. Need to set the data source member of the combo box under property and then choose the correct Display Member